# Thunar custom actions - how to import selections into zsh script

Tags: scripting, zsh, thunar

Xubuntu 22.04 Thunar 4.16

I am working on a script that works similarly to detox but does not require root privileges as it will only be allowed to operate on files or folders in the user's home directory providing that the file itself is not hidden or that there are no hidden folders anywhere in its path.

The idea here is to navigate to a given folder using Thunar and if I see a file or folder that contains, for example, either white spaces or dots used as delimiters, I could right click on the file and initiate a zsh script that would remove illegal characters, etc and output a filename in Title case with lower case extension using underscores as delimiters.

Under Edit/Configure custom actions/command I have

`xfce4-terminal -e "/home/terry/bin/thunar_custom_actions/ffn.sh  -- %F"`

the script is, of course, executable.

The only hint I've managed to find to allow the script to import the selections is
`for <var> in "$@"; do`

I have also tried
`for <var> in %F; do`

but all I get is the terminal opening and immediately closing again.

Any hints, suggestions or ideas how I can resolve this?

Comment: You didn't post the content of `ffn.sh` and it's not clear what you want it to do. “all I get is the terminal opening and immediately closing again” — well, sure, the script runs, then it exits and the terminal closes. What different thing to you want to happen?

Comment: The script is not finished but what I want to do is manipulate the file name - remove illegal characters, ensure name does not begin with white space, convert white spaces / dots used as delimiters to underscores and output the name in title case with lower case extensions. In the case of video files it will consult a user-defined list for elements to remove, perform simple transcoding and normalize audio. Just having some issues learning yad (yet another dialog), but I'm getting there.

Answer (score 0):

I got it figured out! For some reason I tried using 'find', which goofed everything up.

opened thunar
edit -> configure custom actions -> command: /home/terry/bin/thunar_custom_actions/ffn.sh %F

Using perl rename I tried 'rename 'y/A-Z/a-z/'  $@' in the script and it recursively changed the name to lower case.